# Elementarmatrices to get row-echolon-form

Tags: linear-algebra

I need to determine the Elementarmatrice(s) that satisfy:

$M_1M_2...M_nA=B$ where B is in row echolonform
but has the same dimension then A.

So basicly how do you describe swapping of lines, or substracting some with matrices?

Comment: It's all [on Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_matrix).

Comment: "Elementarmatrix" ist Deutsch, das englische Wort ist "elementary matrix".

Comment: is it nescassary that my elementary matrices are the bare minimum or can i give a satisfying set of matrices, which have redundant pieces in it? (like "too many" times (-1) in a delayed way etc. which could be just one matrix)

Comment: That would depend on what your professor wants. For example, you can swap row 1 with row 2, and then row 2 with row 1, and you would have basically done nothing.

Comment: I got a wierd question: why do i have to name my matrices $M_n$ while n is the FIRST step i do to get echolon, and then $M_(n-1)$ is the second step i did. so $M_1$ is the last step i did to get my echolon form. why is that? (in respect to the $M_1*...*M_n$ calculation)

Comment: Well, because you wrote it that way? It would be less confusing if you wrote $M_nM_{n-1}\cdots M_1A=B$ instead.

Comment: no, i mean $M_1$ should be, so i thought, the first step, why it is the last step? has nothing to do with my notation really, i just dont get it, from a basic understanding.

Comment: Because you wrote it that way.

Comment: $M_1M_2\cdots M_nA=M_1(M_2(\cdots(M_nA))))))))$, so $M_1$ is the last matrix to be multiplied.

Comment: Ok, so your $M_nM_{n-1}\cdots M_1A=B$ equation should be really the standardway to write that down or? its just my excercise thats that way

Comment: I don't really know which way is the *standard* way, but $M_nM_{n-1}\cdots M_1A$ would be less confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Think about what happens when you multiply $A$ on the left by a row vector, i.e., a $1\times n$ matrix—the result is a linear combination of the rows of $A$. As a special case of this, multiplying by the vector that has a $1$ in the $k$th column and zeros everywhere else “picks out” the $k$th row of $A$. When you multiply $A$ by some multi-row matrix $M$, that’s the same as multiplying by a series of row vectors, one for each row of $M$.